# Error while passing props through siblings

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

Here i'm passing props value from `Navbar` to `Home` and it works as expected, but the console shows error as: `Cannot update a component ('App') while rendering a different component ('Home'). To locate the bad setState() call inside 'Home', follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render` and the error is shown in `Home` component as below.

```
function App(){
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  return(
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/Home" element={
          <>
            <Navbar login={login}/>
            <Home setlogin={setLogin}/>
          </>
        } />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Navbar (Child 1)

```
function Navbar(login) {
  console.log(login);
}
export default Navbar;
```

Home (Child 2)

```
function Home(props) {
  if (condtion) {
    props.setlogin(true);  //showing error
  } else {
    props.setlogin(false);
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

you're close! But you just have a few things muddled up.

The error message was alluding a setState that wasn't handled properly.

To change state via a function, passing from parent > child, for readability sake, I would create a function that handles it for you.

```
const handleLogin = (bool) => setLogin(bool);
```

Next, we hand that as a prop to pass down to the homepage component:

```
<Home handleLogin={handleLogin} />
```

Within the homepage component, we want to check for a `"condition"`. Because React is reactive, we need to use the right tools to check if something has updated. For this example we need `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (true) {
    handleLogin(true);
  } else {
    handleLogin(false);
  }
}, []);
```

In the `Navbar` component, you forgot to destructure the props so it wouldn't have worked anyway. Change this:

```
function Navbar(login) {
```

To this:

```
function Navbar({ login }) {
```

[Check out this sandbox to see it.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-chebyshev-yu1q1?file=/src/App.js)